# What is the math to raycasting done in geometry nodes, without actually using the raycast node

Tags: geometry-nodes

Basically, I want to recreate raycasting without using the raycast node. Why? The way the raycast node works now, is that one geometry casts onto another geometry.  And that's all great and fine, until you have the crazy idea to make a single geometry cast onto itself.  Then it gets tricky. The raycast node can't help but to hit the geometry at the very start of a ray.  And for that reason, you have to use some scaling tricks to avoid that. That much was explained to me here: [Can an object raycast onto itself?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/290346/can-an-object-raycast-onto-itself)

Well, scaling the rays just isn't good enough for me. I want more accurate self ray casting. And so I guess if I can figure out the math for raycasting, I can alter whatever variable needs to be altered to avoid hitting at the origin of a ray. But... raycasting math is proving too difficult for me to get on my own. Maybe someone here knows how it's done.

[image]

I was thinking something like instancing lines out of points and/or faces of the mesh. Those would act as rays. Then some magic math happens, bibbidi-Bobbidi-Boo, and those lines sample where they intersect faces.

I found a couple of papers explaining how rays are made and how hit detection work. It's just way too advanced for me: [https://people.computing.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/405/notes/raycast.pdf](https://people.computing.clemson.edu/%7Edhouse/courses/405/notes/raycast.pdf)
https://research.ncl.ac.uk/game/mastersdegree/gametechnologies/physicstutorials/1raycasting/Physics%20-%20Raycasting.pdf

This video really breaks it down too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOeOuZGmeCM

I would appreciate any help with this, as impractical as it may sound.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why "Well, scaling the rays just isn't good enough for me" ?

Comment: Can't you separate the mesh to "raycast" from one partition to the others ? Is the Ray Direction uniform or local ?

Comment: @lemon It's not that it doesn't work. It works. But say you deform the mesh, and the that small .001 difference suddenly isn't enough to prevent the mesh from getting hit by the starting position.  So you have to adjust it a little farther out. But then if two faces are near each other, and the starting positions of the rays are too far offset, the rays will overlap awkwardly with nearby faces and get bad hits.

Comment: @Smeebit, recreating a raycast in gn (even if it may be possible (?)) will be difficult and most likely inefficient, except if very special cases. Efficient raycast involves particular data structures that cannot be available in gn. That's why it would be better to study how it can be adapted for your case.

Comment: @StefLAncien I don't understand the question.  Separate the mesh how? Rays can all point in different directions at the same time. So I guess local? I prefer to have them face the direction of the normals.

Comment: @lemon My ultimate goal is to figure out how to make a mesh collide with itself. If you can think of some adaptive way to do that, then I'm all ears. But from from I've been gathering, the most promising road seems to be lead to raycasting. Only, I can't compromise on even that small offset of ray source position.

Certainly it can be done with geometry nodes. It's just a matter of math, right? You build the ray, then nearest doobly-do, and dot product. Something like that. It doesn't seem impossible at all.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more: what do you mean by "colliding with itself"? Does it change its form over time? or is it to know if it statically intersects?

Comment: Yes, it changes form. The raycast checks for intersections, and then it adjusts the mesh back so that it no longer intersects. I mean, hypothetically.  
I haven't exactly figured out part where the mesh adjusts yet. I *kinda* did it before, where I was able to prevent a mesh from passing beyond a plane, no matter how it deformed.(I might be able to reproduce it, but I broke that node a while back after testing went too far, and it became a jumbled mess) I'm not exactly looking for simulation either. But I'll take a simulation solution too, if you think you have one.

Comment: in general case, you can not check for an intersection with a raycast from vertices. But above that you can lower the shift (prev question/answer) so that it's not noticeable. Eventually, you can loop (repeat zone) in order to search for more accurate results.

Comment: You can raycast from geometry to itself . Offset the ray Source Position by an epsilon of. say, the Normal, at the ray source.

Comment: @RobinBetts, yes, this is that https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/290396/19156... but for some reason that is not what Smeebit expects.

Comment: @Smeebit "that small .001 difference suddenly isn't enough to prevent the mesh from getting hit by the starting position"  I would recommend posting a file where this is the case.  Note that in the linked answer, they're offsetting in Z axis; wiser would be to tune the axis of offset to what you need to do.  .001 should always be enough to prevent ray asting onto self-- same with even smaller offsets-- and even if you do the math from scratch, you'll have precision issues at some point.  If you focus on the particular problem you're having, you'll probably get better answers.

Comment: @Nathan I forget how I measured the bad hits before. This was months ago. I'm only just now getting around to asking how to fix the issue. I should have asked long ago when it was still fresh in mind. Regardless, I uploaded a test file, so you can see that I got the ray source positions scaling correctly along the direction of the normals.

Comment: I guess it's one more time for me to be an a-hole, but if you fail to explain in the question why you need to implement raycasting yourself, you will most definitely fail to implement raycasting yourself :P I'm inclined to downvote based on unclear question, XY problem, as well as the problem "not being fresh" (you could refresh it first before presenting it; though there's nothing wrong with an open discussion like that, just that Stack Exchange is not designed for such discussion, blenderartists.org or discord seem better...)

Comment: The question is very very clear. Is raycast-like function possible to replicate using geometry nodes, without using the "raycast node". If yes: then how. If no: then my question is answered, and I try something else.
Asking me *why* I need to do a thing, is opening up long term discussion. Yes, sometimes asking "why" can lead to better problem solving. However, sometimes asking "why" doesn't lead to an answer that you personally find satisfying. Which is fine. You don't always need to know why a thing needs to be done, in order for it to be done.

Comment: @Smeebit Looking at the file.  Everything seems to be working fine.  You can reduce the value to 0.000001, probably even smaller, and it will still avoid self-casting.  But if your goal is to somehow eliminate self-intersection, this plan of self-projection isn't going to do it.  It's nothing to do with the rays missing a target or hitting themselves-- it's just the fact that it won't do what you want, regardless of how perfect the rays are.

Comment: Issue is not in Raycast node, but in floating point error. Collision detection should not be done by using Rays, but other (like BVH, KDT, AABB collision, ..., see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection). This is not generally implemented in geometry nodes now. But just recreating Raycast doesn't works for you due root issue of such approach.

Answer (score 2):

@Smeebit

I think offsetting is still the best option.

if you want to get self collisions (which i see from the comments), then offset the (input) position of the raycast by some small amount in the direction of it's velocity [normalize the velocity then scale my small value, then add to position, and this position is *source position* of raycast].

Through this, it is offset in the directions it is casting and won't hit itself.

If it has no velocity, then calculate as no hit. if you still want to check if it hit itself, then you could input the index into the value input (set it to integer) and compare the output if equal to the index; if it is, then it hit itself (the same vert that cast) so consider it no hit.

I hope this helps.

(btw if you always want the same offset out from the point, then take the sign (not sine) of the dot product between the normal and direction (normalized) and multiply the epsilon (the small value offset) and scale the normal by that and add that to the position (this all as the *source position*))

---

If you want to recreate raycast, you'd have to loop through all faces per vertex. This is a complexity of $xn$ (close to $x^2$); $x$ being vertices and $n$ being faces [but really it's more, because per face you have to go through it's vertices etc.). It's possible, but not recommended.

two ways of doing it.

1. Repeat Zone -

   - set iterations to the vert count
   - and in each iteration have every face sample a single vertexes directory and position and do an intersection
     (you also might have to triangulate the mesh to make the calculation).
   - capture (or store) the hit position of the intersection on that vertex.
     this repeats for all vertices.
   - You'll get multiple answers if it intersects multiple faces. You have to use a dot product or something and compare the one with the least distance that isn't that of the vertex itself.
2. Same thing but duplicate the mesh $n$ times.

   - for each duplicate use the duplicate index to sample the index with Index.
   - to sample back to the vertex use the vertex index + and accumulate ......‍♂️

Anyway, I highly don't recommend.

Answer (score 1):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

*NB: This is not a full answer; it is to illustrate mesh partitioning.*

The approach is to split the geometry in two, and to send rays from on partition toward the other. Setting the *Separate Geometry* node in *Point* domain avoids duplicated points, leading otherwise to seemingly self-intersection. An *Attribute Statistics* node is useful to get the minimal distance, that can be accumulated and compared to a threshold. For complex geometries, both ways (i.e. *Selection* <-> *Inverted*) can be tested and more than one partitioning strategy can be combined.

[image: GN graph]

Resources: [image]